# How to keep audio when converting to MPG with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, mpg

I'm converting a video to MPG and the output has NO audio. I know I should specify the audio stream but can't find how in the documentation.

I need MPEG as output container because I stream my videos in my web app using jsmpeg and that's the required format.
Thanks in advance!

```
ffmpeg -i bunny.mp4 -f mpeg1video -vf scale=1600:900 -y bunny.mpg
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsmpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg) doesn't say anything about being able to play audio - seems to be a video-only decoder.

If you run `ffprobe bunny.mpg` you can check if the output has audio or not. If your ffmpeg build has or is linked with `libmp3lame` or `libtwolame`, it will.

Comment: Thanks for the ffmpeg command.
We actually implemented our own audio context, so jsmpeg can read a separate audio track and play it simultaneously to the video.
I discovered the ffmpeg option "-target pal-dvd" and this keeps the audio.

Comment: Isn't PAL DVD creating a MPEG-2 stream? Does jsmpeg decode that?

Comment: Not sure about PAL DVD, but jsmpeg is decoding my videos right now.